# Socket.io io.emit() not working, communication from server to client is not working. Need a way to send data from server to client through io.emit()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, ejs

The program i made is a document converter that takes in a document and converts it to pdf using libreoffice.

This is my server (localhost:3000)

```
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import multer from "multer"; //To communicate files
import { dirname, extname } from "path";
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";
import fs from "fs";
import { exec } from "child_process"; //Used to execute shell commands
import util from "util"; //built-in Node.js module that provides utility functions.

import { createServer } from 'node:http';
import { Server } from 'socket.io';



const execPromise = util.promisify(exec); // creates a Promise-based version of the exec function to use with asynchronous operations.


const __dirname = dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)); //To get the whole path upto working directory

const TestServer = express();
const port = 3000;

const server = createServer(TestServer);
const io = new Server(server);


TestServer.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
TestServer.use(express.static("public"));



let docName;

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, 'public/Document');
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        //console.log(file);
        docName = file.originalname;
        cb(null, file.originalname);
    }
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

TestServer.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
        // A Multer error occurred (e.g., file size exceeded)
        res.status(400).send('Multer error: ' + err.message);
    } else if (err) {
        // An unknown error occurred
        res.status(500).send('Unknown error: ' + err.message);
    } else {
        // No error occurred, proceed to the next middleware or route handler
        next();
    }
});

//function to check if a particular file exists
function fileExists(filePath) {
    try {
        fs.accessSync(filePath, fs.constants.F_OK);
        return true;
    } catch (err) {
        return false;
    }
}


let pathToOffice;

const osPlatform = process.platform;

if (osPlatform === 'win32' || osPlatform === 'win64') {
    pathToOffice = 'C:\\Program Files\\LibreOffice\\program\\soffice.exe';
} else if (osPlatform === 'darwin') {
    pathToOffice = '/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/soffice';
} else if (osPlatform === 'linux') {
    pathToOffice = '' // have to enter the path according to how soffice is in linux //TODO
} else {
    console.error('Unsupported operating system');
    process.exit(1);
}


async function convertWordToPdf(inputPath, outputPath) {
    try {
        // Convert using LibreOffice
        const { stdout, stderr } = await execPromise(`"${pathToOffice}" --headless --invisible --convert-to pdf --outdir "${outputPath}" "${inputPath}"`);
        if (stderr && !stderr.includes('Secure coding is not enabled for restorable state!')) {
            throw new Error(stderr);
        }
        //console.log('Conversion successful:', stdout);

    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error converting Word to PDF:', error);
        throw error;
    }
}



TestServer.get("/", (req, res) => {
    //send homepage
    res.render("uploadDoc.ejs");
});


TestServer.post("/getdocument", upload.fields([
    { name: 'doc-upload', maxCount: 1 }
]), async (req, res) => {
    console.log(`Document successfully uploaded: ${docName}`);

    //console.log(req.body);

    console.log("---------------------------------------------------------------");


    io.emit('uploadStatus', { status: 'uploading' });
    //Convert process below and send the file
    try {
        if (fileExists(__dirname + `/public/Document/${docName}`)) {
            const docNameWithoutExtension = docName.replace(extname(docName), '');
            io.emit('uploadStatus', { status: 'converting' });
            await convertWordToPdf(__dirname + `/public/Document/${docName}`, __dirname + `/public/Document/${docNameWithoutExtension}`);
            io.emit('uploadStatus', { status: 'complete' });
            res.render("downloadDoc.ejs", {
                filepath: `/Document/${docNameWithoutExtension}/${docNameWithoutExtension}.pdf`
            });
        }
        else {
            res.send("<h1>UNSUCCESSFUL: File not found</h1>");
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Failed to make conversion:", error.message);
        res.send("<h1>UNSUCCESSFUL: Conversion failed</h1>");
    }


});


io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('a user connected');

    // Send initial status to connected client
    socket.on('formSubmit', (msg) => {
        console.log(msg.data);
        io.emit('uploadStatus', { status: 'idle' });

    });


    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });
});


server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

and below is my client side where i am uploading a document

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Upload Doc</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/styles.css">
</head>

<body class="m-0 p-0">

    <div class="bouncing-blobs-container">
        <div class="bouncing-blobs-glass"></div>
        <div class="bouncing-blobs">
            <div class="bouncing-blob bouncing-blob--blue"></div>
            <div class="bouncing-blob bouncing-blob--blue"></div>
            <div class="bouncing-blob bouncing-blob--blue"></div>
            <div class="bouncing-blob bouncing-blob--white"></div>
            <div class="bouncing-blob bouncing-blob--purple"></div>
            <div class="bouncing-blob bouncing-blob--purple"></div>
            <div class="bouncing-blob bouncing-blob--pink"></div>
        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="px-36 py-4 h-screen w-screen">
        <form id="form" action="/getdocument" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="space-y-12">
                <label for="document-upload-area" class="block text-sm font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900">Document
                    Upload</label>

                <div class="mt-2 flex gap-4 justify-center">
                    <p class="text-sm self-center">Convert</p>
                    <select id="convert-from" name="convert-from" required
                        class="block w-full rounded-md border-0 py-1.5 text-gray-900 shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-600 sm:max-w-xs sm:text-sm sm:leading-6">
                        <option value="" disabled selected>--Select--</option>
                        <option value="doc">DOCX, DOC</option>
                        <option value="other-format">Other Format</option>
                    </select>

                    <p class="text-sm self-center">to</p>

                    <select id="convert-to" name="convert-to" required
                        class="block w-full rounded-md border-0 py-1.5 text-gray-900 shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-600 sm:max-w-xs sm:text-sm sm:leading-6">
                        <option value="" disabled selected>--Select--</option>
                        <option value="pdf">PDF</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="mt-2 flex justify-center rounded-lg border border-dashed border-gray-900/25 px-6 py-10">
                    <div>
                        <svg class="mx-auto" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                            xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="40" zoomAndPan="magnify"
                            viewBox="0 0 30 30.000001" height="40" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" version="1.0">
                            <defs>
                                <clipPath id="id1">
                                    <path
                                        d="M 2.742188 3.484375 L 27.417969 3.484375 L 27.417969 25.257812 L 2.742188 25.257812 Z M 2.742188 3.484375 "
                                        clip-rule="nonzero" />
                                </clipPath>
                            </defs>
                            <g clip-path="url(#id1)">
                                <path fill="rgb(8.239746%, 42.349243%, 86.669922%)"
                                    d="M 15.082031 3.484375 L 2.742188 5.902344 L 2.742188 22.839844 L 15.082031 25.257812 Z M 17.546875 5.902344 L 17.546875 8.324219 L 20.015625 8.324219 L 20.015625 10.742188 L 17.546875 10.742188 L 17.546875 13.160156 L 20.015625 13.160156 L 20.015625 15.582031 L 17.546875 15.582031 L 17.546875 18 L 20.015625 18 L 20.015625 20.417969 L 17.546875 20.417969 L 17.546875 22.839844 L 27.417969 22.839844 L 27.417969 5.902344 Z M 22.484375 8.324219 L 24.953125 8.324219 L 24.953125 10.742188 L 22.484375 10.742188 Z M 5.425781 9.890625 L 7.621094 9.890625 L 8.757812 12.570312 C 8.851562 12.789062 8.921875 13.042969 8.992188 13.332031 L 9.023438 13.332031 C 9.066406 13.160156 9.148438 12.894531 9.273438 12.550781 L 10.542969 9.890625 L 12.542969 9.890625 L 10.15625 14.332031 L 12.613281 18.851562 L 10.480469 18.851562 L 9.105469 15.929688 C 9.054688 15.828125 8.992188 15.621094 8.941406 15.332031 L 8.921875 15.332031 C 8.890625 15.46875 8.832031 15.675781 8.738281 15.953125 L 7.351562 18.851562 L 5.210938 18.851562 L 7.753906 14.367188 Z M 22.484375 13.160156 L 24.953125 13.160156 L 24.953125 15.582031 L 22.484375 15.582031 Z M 22.484375 18 L 24.953125 18 L 24.953125 20.417969 L 22.484375 20.417969 Z M 22.484375 18 "
                                    fill-opacity="1" fill-rule="nonzero" />
                            </g>
                        </svg>
                        <div class="mt-4 flex text-sm leading-6 text-gray-600 justify-center">
                            <label for="doc-upload"
                                class="relative cursor-pointer rounded-md bg-transparent font-semibold text-indigo-600 focus-within:outline-none focus-within:ring-2 focus-within:ring-indigo-600 focus-within:ring-offset-0 hover:text-indigo-500">
                                <span>Upload a file</span>
                                <input id="doc-upload" name="doc-upload" type="file" class="sr-only">
                            </label>
                            <p class="pl-1">or drag and drop</p>
                        </div>
                        <p id="doc-name" class="text-lg leading-5 text-gray-600 text-center"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="buttons" class="mt-6 justify-center gap-x-6 hidden">
                <a href="/" class="flex justify-center items-center">
                    <button type="button" class="text-sm font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-900">Cancel</button>
                </a>
                <button id="submit-btn" type="submit"
                    class="rounded-md bg-indigo-600 px-3 py-2 text-sm font-semibold text-white shadow-sm hover:bg-indigo-500 focus-visible:outline focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-offset-2 focus-visible:outline-indigo-600">Convert</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('doc-upload').addEventListener('change', function () {
            // File has been selected, show the buttons
            document.getElementById('buttons').classList.remove("hidden");
            document.getElementById('buttons').classList.add("flex");


            // Display the selected file name
            const fileNameElement = document.getElementById('doc-name');
            const fileInput = document.getElementById('doc-upload');

            if (fileInput.files.length > 0) {
                fileNameElement.textContent = fileInput.files[0].name;
            } else {
                // Reset the text if no file is selected
                fileNameElement.textContent = 'word DOCX and DOC';
            }
        });

        //Animation taken from a youtube video which i cant remember.

        const MIN_SPEED = 1.5
        const MAX_SPEED = 2.5

        function randomNumber(min, max) {
            return Math.random() * (max - min) + min
        }

        class Blob {
            constructor(el) {
                this.el = el
                const boundingRect = this.el.getBoundingClientRect()
                this.size = boundingRect.width
                this.initialX = randomNumber(0, window.innerWidth - this.size)
                this.initialY = randomNumber(0, window.innerHeight - this.size)
                this.el.style.top = `${this.initialY}px`
                this.el.style.left = `${this.initialX}px`
                this.vx =
                    randomNumber(MIN_SPEED, MAX_SPEED) * (Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : -1)
                this.vy =
                    randomNumber(MIN_SPEED, MAX_SPEED) * (Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : -1)
                this.x = this.initialX
                this.y = this.initialY
            }

            update() {
                this.x += this.vx
                this.y += this.vy
                if (this.x >= window.innerWidth - this.size) {
                    this.x = window.innerWidth - this.size
                    this.vx *= -1
                }
                if (this.y >= window.innerHeight - this.size) {
                    this.y = window.innerHeight - this.size
                    this.vy *= -1
                }
                if (this.x <= 0) {
                    this.x = 0
                    this.vx *= -1
                }
                if (this.y <= 0) {
                    this.y = 0
                    this.vy *= -1
                }
            }

            move() {
                this.el.style.transform = `translate(${this.x - this.initialX}px, ${this.y - this.initialY
                    }px)`
            }
        }

        function initBlobs() {
            const blobEls = document.querySelectorAll('.bouncing-blob')
            const blobs = Array.from(blobEls).map((blobEl) => new Blob(blobEl))

            function update() {
                requestAnimationFrame(update)
                blobs.forEach((blob) => {
                    blob.update()
                    blob.move()
                })
            }

            requestAnimationFrame(update)
        }

        initBlobs()

        

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

I tried integrating socket.io to send updates to client, based on when document is uploaded, when conversion starts and when it is complete. But i cant find a way to send the data to the client side. From the client side i am able to send some data via firing an event, but that is not what i want. I basically need the server to be able to send the updates to the client side somehow.

Backend is done using NodeJS, Express. Front end uses EJS, tailwind to render data from server to client.

Answer (score 0):

There are several points you need to consider.

There is no implementation of socket client on the client side.
You just created socket.io on the server side, you need to implement the connections on the client side.

I have reservations about server implementations as well. You should create a separate socket.io server and connect to that and express APIs should be separate.

Your client implementation should look like this.

```js
<script src="http://localhost:4000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io('http://localhost:4000', {
        transports: [ 'websocket' ],
        'reconnection': true,
        'reconnectionDelay': 500,
        'reconnectionDelayMax': 1000,
        'reconnectionAttempts': 100
    });

    socket.on('connect', onConnect);
    socket.on('disconnect',onDisconnect);
    
    socket.on('connect_error', function(){
        console.log('Connection Failed');
    });

function onConnect(){
    console.log('Connected Successully...'); 
}
function onDisconnect(){
    console.log('Client disconnected');
}
</script>
```

Once you implement the client connection to your socket.io server. Now the server should be able to send events to the client.
But in your case, it will not work. You want to invoke the Socket.io event using your webapi call.

And to that, you need to implement "socket.io-emitter"

You can get more details from

https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-emitter

or updated version from socket.io itself (recommended)

https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-redis-emitter

Then you need to manage the SocketID of the client. Send it to your API post as an additional parameter as your API does not know the SocketID to send the event,

You can get the Client socket ID in the connect function something like (On Client Side)

```js
function onConnect(){
    console.log('Client Connected Successully...'); 
     let ClientSocketID= socket.id;

}
```

This in your API you need to use “socket.io-emitter” or
updated version “@socket.io/redis-emitter”

you will need redis server installed, https://redis.io/

and you need to install redis client
npm install redis.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis

```js
const { Emitter } = require("@socket.io/redis-emitter");
const { createClient } = require("redis"); 

const redisClient = createClient();

const io = new Emitter(redisClient);

io.to(CLIENT_SOCKET_ID).emit('EVENTNAME,SOME-JSON-Object);
```

Summary:
1: create 2 separate projects webapis and Socket.io server

2: implement socket.io client on client side and connect to socket.io server.

3: Implement socket.io-redis-emitter in your APIs and pass client SocketID to it. and emit